# Do you know how to bake a normal map from a diffuse map?

Tags: uv, shaders, texture-baking, baking, normal-map

I have a little problem with baking on Blender.

I have a backpack model on which I have a diffusion map that I made with texture paint and that I would like to change to a normal map.

[image: BagPack with only Diffuse]

I use a converter (http://cpetry.github.io/NormalMap-Online/) which gives me a normal map from the diffuse but there are some shading problems once imported in Blender (especially on the UV seams and generally on the edges).

[image: BagPack with Diffuse and Normal]

[image: Edges and Seams problem]

I tried to add a surface subdivision, to change the shading mode or to play with the auto smooth but nothing works. Even by changing the parameters of the normal map in the shader editor (non-color, etc ...) or from the converter  but nothing seems to work...

I put you the DiffuseMap and the NormalMap as attachments if you want to see what they look like.

I'm out of ideas, if you have a miracle solution or a different way to do it I'm interested!

Thanks in advance !

(sorry for my english, that's not my native language)

[image: DiffuseMap]

[image: NormalMap]

Comment: You don't "bake" a normal  map from a diffuse map. The only thing that can give you an accurate normal map to bake from is higher detailed geometry. Converters do just that: convert. It's far from perfect. Besides, looking at your diffuse, we see the shading is already included. The point of feeding your shader with normals and other data maps is to let the shader calculate reflections, bumps, shadows and whatnot. It's a bit counterproductive to have both info baked in your diffuse and also in your normal and other maps.

Comment: If you really want to get a normal map from a diffuse, only converters do that. Make sure you set your normal map's texture node color management setting to "non-color" so the shader interprets it correctly. Otherwise, I'd advise you to model a highly detailed version of your mesh and bake that geometry detail into maps.

Comment: As Lolock I suspect it's a problem of Image Texture setting (switch to non-color instead of sRGB), but if it's not the case, please share your file

Comment: Make sure you shade smooth your object, also during baking!

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply, in the end I went back to a higpoly to be able to bake more easily on the low-poly and not to make a wobbly thing with only the diffuser...

Nevertheless I had connected the normal map to a normalmap node before connecting it to the "normal" connector of the principled BSDF and switch the image to "non-color" but it was not enough ...

Thanks for your help :)